Is it possible to use gratia::difference_smooths() to compare only certain smooths (not all) in a modGI GAM?
The model I am using is the following :
modGI <- gam(Met1 ~ s(Timepoint, k=7) + s(Timepoint, by=subject, k=7, 
             m=1) + s(subject, bs="re"), data=df, method="REML")

smooths(modGI)

"s(Timepoint)"  "s(Timepoint):subject1"  "s(Timepoint):subject3" 
    "s(Timepoint):subject4"  "s(Timepoint):subject5" 
    "s(Timepoint):subject6" "s(subject)"

In reality I have a lot more subjects. My question for comparing smooths is two-fold;
a) can I use difference_smooths for this model?
check1 <- difference_smooths(modGI, smooth="s(Timepoint)")

gets
Error in combn(levels(data[[by_var]]), 2) : n < m

b) is it possible to compare the smooths of certain subjects? E.g.
check1 <- difference_smooths(modGI, smooth= c("s(Timepoint):subject1",
           "s(Timepoint):subject2"), partial_match=FALSE)

Error in `pmap()`:ℹ In index: 9. Caused by error in `Xp[r1, ] - Xp[r2,
    ]`: ! non-conformable arrays

As a final question, is it possible to compare first derivatives using gratia (something similar to marginal effects plot_comparisons)?
Any pointers would be appreciated.

I'm pretty sure both of these are bugs; the first error certainly is a bug (most likely due to group means being specified as a random effect not as a fixed effect). The second error is one I've not seen before (mostly because the way you tried first time should have worked). If you get chance, I'd appreciate a bug report: https://github.com/gavinsimpson/gratia/issues to remind me to track this down and fix it.

In the meantime, as OP alluded to, you can do all this with {marginaleffects}: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/645096/interpretation-help-of-summary-from-basic-gam-models-with-random-smooths#645111

@NicholarClark thank you, I found this post and tried to use the marginaleffects approach, but I found with my dataset it took an extremely long time to run, and I have many response variables to assess. Please could you let me know if you're aware of anything that could speed up some of the comparisons ( such as comparing smooths or the first derivatives)? I've been finding out if parallelisation could be used, but no luck so far
